# JQPlot Legend outside of graph

Tags: javascript, html, position, jqplot, legend

I am using JQPlot and I have many graphs on one HTML page. Each of the graphs has the same legend.

My question is this: Is it possible to display a legend totally outside of the graph with its own position on the HTML page or in its own div?

Answer (score 8):

```
legend:{ 
                show:true,
                    renderer: $.jqplot.EnhancedLegendRenderer,
                    location: 's' ,
                    placement : "outside",
                    marginTop : "30px",
                    rendererOptions: {
                        numberRows: 1
                    }
                 },
```

You can use placement : "outside" like in the above code. And you can move it using marginTop,marginBottom,marginRight,marginLeft properties.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you could hide the legend of the 2nd to the last graph, like this:

```
legend: { show:false}
```

and in the 1st graph, put something like:

```
 legend:{
        show:true, 
        placement: 'outside', 
        rendererOptions: {
            numberRows: 1
        }, 
        location:'n'
```

This way you will only show one legend at the top of the graphs.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for `title`? You can style .jqplot-title to appear differently. It appears outside of the graph by default.

```
$.jqplot('chartdiv',  [[[1, 2],[3,5.12],[5,13.1],[7,33.6],[9,85.9],[11,219.9]]],
{ title:'Exponential Line',
  axes:{yaxis:{min:-10, max:240}},
  series:[{color:'#5FAB78'}]
});
```

You could also restyle the legend. See `table.jqplot-table-legend` at http://www.jqplot.com/docs/files/jqPlotCssStyling-txt.html