# Using JQPlot, how can I place the legend outside the chart in a specific location?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqplot

I am using the following to successfully place the legend outside my JQPlot line chart:

```
legend: {
   show: true,
   location: 'sw',
   placement: 'outside'
},
```

However, this places the legend too close to the chart, in line with my yaxis labeling. I need to move it further to the left. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: refer to this post, i have posted the answer

[is-it-possible-to-write-legend-to-a-separate-division-with-jqplot](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16832218/is-it-possible-to-write-legend-to-a-separate-division-with-jqplot/16905943)

Comment: Here is the answer, maybe some other developers needs. http://stackoverflow.com/a/20047827/2371672

Answer (score 6):

A bit late, sure, but I got it!
You should use
`placement: 'outsideGrid'` instead of `placement: 'outside'` as 'outsideGrid' will shrink the graph area for the legend not to be mixed with it.

Answer (score 4):

Checkout the marginTop, marginRight, marginBottom, marginLeft properties for [Legend](http://www.jqplot.com/docs/files/jqplot-core-js.html#Legend.marginTop).

You should be able to do:

```
legend: { 
    show: true, 
    location: 'sw', 
    placement: 'outside',
    marginLeft: 300
}
```

Comment: I have attempted the marginLeft solution, but without success. I tried all 4 of the following, 1 at a time: marginLeft, marginRight, marginTop, marginBottom; none of them move the legend. Is there something else I need to include? I have not yet attempted the solution offered by @Gyandeep, but will if I can't get this simpler solution to work for my needs. Thanks to all.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use it like this. `marginLeft : "300px"`

```
legend: { 
    show: true, 
    location: 'sw', 
    placement: 'outside',
    marginLeft: "300px"
}
```